# Cyclically sort lists with some repeated elements?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, sorting

This is a continuation of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128784/cyclically-sort-lists-of-mixed-element-types).

In the previous question we got a routine that can take two cyclically equivalent lists and determine their equivalence if all the elements in each list are unique:

```
cyc[list_] := RotateLeft[list, First@Ordering[list, 1]]
```

However, this routine fails e.g. for the lists

```
list1 = {1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1};
list2 = {3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
cyc[list1]==cyc[list2]
```

> `False`

Is there a convenient way to generalize the routine to be able to deal with lists containing repeated elements efficiently as well? Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a duplicate of [How to represent a list as a cycle](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17041/121) and I shall be marking it as such.  Note that `canonize` *greatly* outperforms Carl Woll's `canon` on long lists:

```
canonize[a_List] := 
  With[{X = # ~Extract~ Ordering[#, 1] &},
    RotateLeft[a, # - 1] & /@ Position[a, X @ a] // X
  ]

big = RandomInteger[500, 1000];

canonize@big === canon@big

canon[big];     // RepeatedTiming
canonize[big];  // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> True
>
> {0.0129, Null}
>
> {0.0000548, Null}
> ```

Comment: Are duplicate questions deleted eventually? Curious, since I could delete it right away if thats the case. On the other hand, I would not have thought of searching for "represent list as cycle" to find the answer, so some redundancy in possible titles to search for in order to find this particular answer might be useful...

Comment: @Kagaratsch No, in all but rare cases "duplicate" (or more techincally *already has an answer*) Questions are not deleted and serve as signposts for the original/master Question just as you propose.  ps thanks for the Accept.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
canon[list_] := First @ Sort @ NestList[RotateLeft, list, Length[list]-1]
```

Then:

```
canon[{1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1}]
canon[{3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}]
```

> {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3}
>
> {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3}

Comment: This works great! Should be good enough for short lists, thank you!